# How do you effectively hide a database or API key?

Tags: database, key

I am a what you could call an aspiring game dev. Recently I've been experimenting with making smaller games using python and giving them to others in an executable format so that they can play. I've recently made a game that holds high scores, leaderboard info and such in a local JSON file. I moved this file to an online bin so that it could be accessed by multiple people. The problem I'm having is that I don't know how to properly hide or make unreadable the key that is in my code. Thanks for any help.

I tried looking up the problem on different platforms, and yes stack overflow ofc, but I was unsuccessful

Comment: what kind of online bin? there are a few ways to hide API keys, you can use environment variables or keyring password for example

Comment: I'm using simple JSON storage bin that acts kind of like an API. You can request the data using a HTTP address with the key appended to the end of it. I Know some storage providers give options to help hide your keys but this one doesn't. I've heard of environment variables but frankly i cant figure out what they are, how to make them, or how to use them. I think that's the biggest problem

Comment: maybe you can get some support from whatever JSON bin service you are using then. If you don't control the code/server/system yourself, you can't hide the keys... if they need to be in the JSON. Just search online for "environment variables example". Basically you would do for example `export API_KEY="asdf"` in the shell. And then you can access that from your script (if python) like this: `API_KEY = os.environ.get("API_KEY")`

Comment: okay that makes sense and i now have a vague idea of what environment variables are. What I now don't understand is how that variable itself is shared when I share a program In other words if an environment variable is part of the os environment then how would people who run my game be able to inherit that variable. if that makes any sense.

Comment: that does make sense however environment variables do not work for that. If you share the entire program including the source code, and it is completely independent, you can't have any secrets..

usually what happens is you would have some server, a computer or host your game somewhere, or the information the game needs, and then the applications you share access that.

I believe you can also share your program without the source code, e.g. as an .exe file and that could hide the secret. Don't quote me on that though, possibly .exes can be reverse engineered

Comment: I suppose you do have that API which is on a server, but yeah I don't see how you can have any secrets if you share the entire source code for an app to another computer (except through things like whitelisting IP addresses or something). How are you distributing the program?

Comment: Since its not a big program and more like a play-around thing I was going to use pyInstaller to make it into a windows executable and then either put it on github or share it with a flash drive or something small like that. But that's what I was afraid of. it seemed really hard to hide the keys if they needed to be on someone else's Computer. What really confuses me is if you put information the games needs in a database or server wouldn't you need to have a key to that server in your source code somewhere? Which means someone can just as easily take the data in the server.

Comment: Well yes that is correct.. which is why there must be something more to this which I just don't know. Perhaps storing it in the .exe files is secure :)) there must be some info about this online "how to make application securely talk to a server" etc.

Comment: For sure this is possible and a lot of programs do this

Comment: it's possible. Looks like some more googling is needed. Thanks for taking time to discuss a problem with me.

Comment: good luck, please post an answer when you figure it out :)

Comment: So pyinstaller was giving me trouble but I finally figured it out. I was able to use pyinstaller to turn the program into a executable exe file which hides the source code. The only way I can see for someone to get the API key is to maybe decompile it. Otherwise it works perfectly. Thanks again for your help.